# Excel RANDOM (after underscore) suffix removal

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of information and certain entries end with a underscore followed by either a one or two digit number like so:

```
b_labla_bla_67

afdsfsfwer_8

fasd_dfd_fda
```

The complicated part about this is that underscores are also used in the cell at other places as well, but basically, if the last underscore is followed by a number, it needs to be removed.

Is there any way that a script could be written for this?

EDIT: The rest of the cell doesn't have any numbers, just the suffix. Therefore, I was able to use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE _
 (SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE _ 
  (D2,"1",""),"0",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9","")
```

Comment: Yup there is a way, but Stack Overflow is not the place for that.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: I don't need a code for me, I can do the coding. I need the idea. The process

Comment: so this `b_labla_bla_67` has to change to `b_labla_bla`  ??

Comment: We are not here to show you where to start.  this is a site dedicated to helping those with existing code that have a specific problem with that code.

Comment: Here is one slow way, turn your string into a char array, reverse it and check if the first character is a number, if it is, check if the next character is a number or underscore, truncate there if underscore or repeat, after truncate, reverse back and save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1))),LEFT(A1,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))))-1),A1)
```

[image]

If you want the last `_` to stay on the text, remove the `-1` from the formula

Comment: yep that worked perfectly and makes sense too. Thank you so much!

Comment: @HonestlyP Thats great